# Ubuntu 16.04 black screen and login bootloop

Tags: 16.04

I was trying to set up remote desktop access to a Ubuntu 16.04 machine we have at work, using either RDP or VNC. I installed xrdp and tightvncserver through ssh, but neither of them worked in the end. However, in the in the process of trying to get these to work, something got corrupted. I can ssh and also use WinSCP to access the contents of that machine, but am no longer able to login. As soon as I login I am prompted with a system program error, followed by a black screen & then it goes back to the login screen. 
Here are the things I have tried, to no avail: uninstalled xrdp and tightvncserver, reinstalled lightDM, changed display manager (lightDM to GDM), changed permissions of Xauthority.

Not really sure how to troubleshoot on Ubuntu, as I'm pretty new to this OS. Could someone please help me?

Comment: This is unlikely to be the issue (it doesn't generate an error message), but GUI logins require space in $HOME (your home directory), so I'd login to via a text terminal to ensure you have enough space for temporary-work-files to be created which are if you attempt gui login.  If insufficient space is available, the gui login just aborts & you returned to greeter (login screen).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I checked the harddrive usage, and I'm only at 17% of capacity.

Comment: Sorry I don't know what you did, but I'd look for clues and reverse it. Package adds/removes can be seen in /var/log/apt/ though i usually just look in my `history` for the commands I used; if you edited conf files then I rely on `history` to tell me what i edited, and my own comments to tell me what & when I changed anything.  by default `history` doesn't include date/time in logs but it's something I usually change on a new install.